# How to install Matplotlib in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python

**Motivation in 14.04:** 16.04 is buggy for production use. 14.04 is the only stable one. 15.10 is also buggy. Their upstart/systemd with runit is horrible.

I run `masi@masi:~/BitTorrentSync/IPython$ sudo -H pip install matplotlib`

```
Collecting matplotlib
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading matplotlib-1.5.1.tar.gz (54.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 54.0MB 26kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.5.1]
                    python: yes [2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)  [GCC
                            4.8.2]]
                  platform: yes [linux2]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.11.0]
                  dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.5.3]
                      pytz: yes [using pytz version 2016.4]
                    cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                   tornado: yes [using tornado version 4.3]
                 pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                            mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                            be found.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                            found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                            matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                            your preferred tool to run the test suite / mock is
                            required to run the matplotlib test suite. Please
                            install it with pip or your preferred tool to run
                            the test suite]
            toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                            matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                            your preferred tool to run the test suite / mock is
                            required to run the matplotlib test suite. Please
                            install it with pip or your preferred tool to run
                            the test suite]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: yes [installing, Qt: 4.8.6, PyQt: 4.8.6; PySide not
                            found]
                   gtk3agg: yes [installing, version 3.8.10]
                 gtk3cairo: yes [installing, version 3.8.10]
                    gtkagg: no  [The C/C++ header for gtk (gtk/gtk.h) could not
                            be found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     tkagg: no  [TKAgg requires Tkinter.]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [The C/C++ header for gtk (gtk/gtk.h) could not
                            be found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: yes [installing, pycairo version 1.8.8]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: yes [version 9.10]
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: yes [version 0.24.5]

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5VdgT2/matplotlib/
```

---

where *error code 1* did not return any corresponding threads. I got exactly the same error when running the command without `sudo -H`. This is incomplete installation, trying to use the module you get

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

Proposal in comment. I run `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libpng12-dev` successfully. I run successfully `sudo -H pip install matplotlib`. However, I get the warning when running matplotlib module now

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
```

---

How can you install matplotlib in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: If you look at the output carefully, you will find the reason. It already tells you that "freetype" and "png" is required dependencies. So you need to install their development packages first. Maybe "sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev libpng12-dev"

Comment: @Masi Also, as a general comment, it seems like you are having trouble installing the matplotlib/ipython stack. You could consider using something like Anaconda to install the usual Python stack needed for scientific work, although you could find it too bloated for what you need.

Comment: @Masi For the font cache warning, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34999763/486919 and delete the necessary caches.

Comment: @Masi I am guessing that the first iteration is indeed building the caches as they don't exist (since you have deleted them previously). On the second iteration, `matplotlib` knows the caches have been created and do exist, so it doesn't bother building them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edwinksl's comment and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34999763/54964). The last warning is the font cache warning. Start `ipython` to find out Matplotlib's cache directory

```
In [2]: import matplotlib
In [3]: matplotlib.get_cachedir()
Out[3]: u'/home/masi/.cache/matplotlib'
```

In my case, delete

```
rm /home/masi/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.cache 
rm -r /home/masi/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/
```

Now, run your matplotlib test code again. I got the same error again with the first run. I run the test code second time, and the case was resolved. Edwinksl's proposal why it has the behaviour

> I am guessing that the first iteration is indeed building the caches since they don't exist. On the second iteration, matplotlib knows the caches exist, so it doesn't bother building them again.